# Adding line break in esc_html__

Tags: wp-login-form

I would like to add line break in the output of `esc_html__` WordPress function. The original code is:

```
echo "<span class='gp-success'>" . esc_html__( 'We have just sent you an email with instructions to reset your password. If you do not receive a reset email or password email please look in your spam folder.', 'socialize' ) . "</span>";
```

It outputs:

```
We have just sent you an email with instructions to reset your password. br If you do not receive a reset email or password email please look in your spam folder.
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
We have just sent you an email with instructions to reset your password. 
If you do not receive a reset email or password email please look in your spam folder.
```

Where this second line: `If you do not receive a reset email or password email please look in your spam folder.` must be in bold and red

Comment: I would write an answer but im currently on mobile, check phps `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks please whenever you get the chance please share with me the code . I tried sprintf or any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way of doing it using sprintf

```php
echo "<span class='gp-success'>" . sprintf(esc_html__('We have just sent you an email with instructions to reset your password.%sIf you do not receive a reset email or password email please look in your spam folder.', 'socialize'), '<br>') . "</span>";
```

Notice the `%s` in the string, this is a "placeholder" for the second and later arguments that are being passed to sprintf.

A side note, in php its better to use `'` instead of `"` for pure strings, `"` also checked the string for variables and thus costs more resources, when you can, if you only want to output a string, use `'`.